# Conditions on $a$,$b$ such that $f(x)$ is is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

A function $f$ is defined:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
ax+b,& x\ge1\\
x^{3}+3x+3, & x\le 1
\end{cases}
$$
For  what  values of  $a$,$b$  is  $f$  differentiable?

Now $f(1)=7$ from  the  second  equation . Then $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{a+ah+b-7}{h}$$ which  is  $a +\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{a+b-7}{h}$ .  Where  can  I  go  with  this? Instead  if  I  write $f(1)=a+b$  then  I  get  a  proper  value  and  the  answer  of  this  question  is  obtained  as  $a=5$  and $b=5$.

But  my  question  is  since  in  the  first  attempt  I  had taken $f(1)=10$,  which  is  correct  by  the  way , why  the  process  could not  be  furthered? Or may  be  it  could  just  I  did  not  get  that. How is  it  then?

Comment: I would say, f(1) = 7  from the second equation.

Comment: Hint: check FIRST continuity and get a relation between $a$ and $b$. Then, substitute this relation in the definition of derivative on both branches.

Comment: The function $f$ is now defined incorrectly, as $f(1)$ has two definitions.

Comment: @molarmass: Of course not. Just choose $a$ and $b$ such that $a+b = 7$. Next impose $a = 6$ and that is it.

Comment: @AlexM. But what if I set $a=7$ and $b=10$? Obviously the function will not be continuous but that need not be the case for a function. However, now I do not know what the definition of $f(1)$ is.

Comment: @molarmass: In order for $f$ to be differentiable (as the OP requires), it is necessary to be continuous.

Comment: @AlexM. The function does not necessarily need to be differentiable for given $a,b$. OP just wants to know for which $a,b$ this happens to be the case. The function should exist for other values of $a,b$ as well.

Comment: @molarmass: Le me quote: *"For what values of $a,b$ is $f$ differentiable?"*. End of discussion.

Comment: @AlexM. I'll not extend the discussion, but in all my knowledge, a function cannot have multiple definitions for the same argument. In case of $f(1)$, their *numerical value* surely will be the same (i.e. $f(1) = 7$ in both cases), but the *definition* is not.

Comment: @moralmass : f  is  not  incorrectly  defined  neither  does  f(1)  have  two  different  values. It  is  a  Problem given  to  solve  with  a,b  unknown . Since f  is said  to be a  function here, the  two  definitions  are  to  be  equal  and  thus  to  give  a Clue  about the  values  of  a,b.

Comment: @moralmass :A  function  can  be  defined  in two  segments  with only  one  point  in  common   with two  different  definitions  for  each  segment  while  taken  care  of  the  thing  that  both  definitions  agree  on  the  common  point i.e.  give  the  same  numerical  value  for  real-valued  functions.  That  is  perfectly  correct  and  well-definedness  is  not  violated  there. Well-definedness  requires   the  uniqueness  of the  image  point not  of  the  path  through  which  that  is  reached.

Comment: The function would be well-defined if you assume that $f$ is differentiable. However, that is not one of the assumptions. You simply state a function $f$ with two parameters, $a$ and $b$. Clearly, there exists a pair $(a,b)$ such that $f$ is differentiable. These are the values you are interested in. But there exist other pairs $(a,b)$ for which $f$ is not differentiable and the function is not well defined. The function $f_{a,b}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ could alternatively be defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases}ax+b & \text{if } x < 1,\\ x^3+3x+3 & \text{if } x \geq 1.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
ax+b,& x\ge1\\
x^{3}+3x+3, & x\le 1
\end{cases}
$$

Now  it  is  differentiable  so  continuous  everywhere. So evaluating  at  point  $1$ we  get  $$f(1)=a+b=7$$(since $f$  has  to  be  well  defined  and  continuous  at  $1$).

Now  for  $f$  to  be  differentiable  at  $1$  , left  hand  derivative  and  right  hand  derivative  at  $1$  must  be  same  i.e.  $f$  is  differentiable if . $${lim_{h\rightarrow 0}} {{f(1)-f(1-h)}\over {h}}={lim_{h\rightarrow 0}} {{f(1+h)-f(1)}\over {h}}$$ i.e.if $$lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{7-[(1-h)^{3} +3(1-h)+3]}\over {h}}=lim_{h\rightarrow 0} {{a(1+h)+b-7}\over {h}}$$ i.e. if $$lim{h\rightarrow 0}{{h^{3}-3h^{2}+6h}\over {h}}=lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{a+b-7+ah}\over {h}}$$ i.e if $$6=a$$ [using  that $a+b=7$],  implying  $b=1$

Then  $f$  is  differentiable  for  $$a=6, b=1$$

Answer (score 3):

Continuity at $1$ requires that $a + b = 7$. Continuity of $f'$ at $1$ requires $a = 6$ (you must have $a = 3x^2 + 3$ for $x=1$). This produces $b = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

A necessary condition is that $a+b=7$ (because $f$ must be well defined and at least continuous at $x=1$ if we want the differentiability at this point).
Next, we have
$$f(1-h)=a(1-h)+b=f(1)-ah\quad\quad\quad h>0$$
and $h\mapsto ah$ is a linear (continuous) map. Moreover,
$$f(1+h)=(1+h)^3+3(1+h)+3=f(1)+6h+3h^2+h^3 \quad\quad\quad h>0$$
and $h\mapsto 6h$ is a linear (continuous) map and $h\mapsto 3h^2+h^3=o(h)$.
Hence, if you ask for the unicity of the limit as $x\to 1$ for the derivative of $f$, we must have $a=6$, which gives $b=1$.

Comment: You've made a mistake somewhere, please double-check.

Comment: @AlexM. Indeed, the linear map is $h\mapsto ah$, and then $-h\mapsto -ah$. Thanks for pointing this mistake out, I correct it.